# kubernetes failing to connect on fresh installation of CoreOS

Tags: json, vagrant, docker, coreos, kubernetes

I'm running (from Windows 8.1) a Vagrant VM for CoreOS ([yungsang/coreos](https://vagrantcloud.com/yungsang/boxes/coreos)).

I installed kubernetes according to the guide I found [here](https://coreos.com/blog/running-kubernetes-example-on-CoreOS-part-1) and created the json for the pod using my images.

When I execute `sudo ./kubecfg list /pods` I get the following error:

```
F0909 06:03:04.626251 01933 kubecfg.go:182] Got request error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1beta1/pods?labels=: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

Same goes for `sudo ./kubecfg -h http://127.0.0.1:8080 -c /vagrant/app.json create /pods`

EDIT: **Update**

Instead of running the commands myself I integrated into the vagrant file (as [such](http://qiita.com/yungsang/items/3cbab1c9a231a995a23d)) .

This makes kubernetes work fine. HOWEVER after some time my vagrant ssh connection gets closed off. I reconnect and any kubernetes commands I specify result in the same error as above.

EDIT 2: **Update**

I managed to get it to run again, however I am unsure if it will run smoothly

I had to re-execute the following commands.

```
sudo systemctl start etcd
sudo systemctl start download-kubernetes
sudo systemctl start apiserver
sudo systemctl start controller-manager
sudo systemctl start kubelet
sudo systemctl start proxy
```

I believe it is in fact the apiserver that needs restarting

What is the source of this "timeout"? (Where are any logs I can find for this matter)

Comment: Dunno if you ever found a solution to this bit I ran across it today.  That error basically means there is something wrong with the apiserver service.  I can provide more details if interested.

Comment: Yes please. This was left on the shelf due to lack of progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes development is moving insanely fast right now so this could be out of date by tomorrow.  With that in mind, the kubernetes folks recommend following one of their [official installation guides](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides).  The best advice would be to start over fresh with one of the new installation guides but there are a few tips that I have learned doing this myself.

The first thing to note is that Kubecfg is being deprecated in favor of kubectl.  So for future reference if you want to get info about a pod you would run something like:

`./kubectl get pods`.

With kubectl you will also need to set an env variable so kubectl know how to talk to the apiserver:

`KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://IPADDRESS:8080`.

The easiest way to debug exactly what is going on if you are using CoreOS is to tail the logs for the service you are interested in.  So if you have a `kube-apiserver` unit you can look at what's goin on by running:

`journalctl -f -u kube-apiserver`

from the node that is running the apiserver.  If that service isn't running, which may be the case, you can start it with:

`systemctl start kube-apiserver`

Comment: Thanks for this. I tripped over a similar problem following the "Real-time data analysis with Kubernetes, Redis, and BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform" tutorial on the Google Cloud Platform site:https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time/kubernetes-redis-bigquery

It refers to kubecfg.sh which has been deprecated in favour of kubectl.sh, as you say.

Comment: @rdc yeah the development is still moving extremely quickly so the docs get out of date really fast still.  Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

On CoreOS you should look at the logs using `journalctl`.

For example, if you wish to see `etcd` logs, which Kubernetes relies on for storing the state of it's minions, run `journalctl _COMM=etcd`, and similarly `journalctl _COMM=apiserver` will show you the logs from the `apiserver`, one of key components in Kubernetes.

You also get last few log entries if you run `systemctl status apiserver`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on errordevelopers advice, my recent installation ran against a similar problem.

Using `systemctl status apiserver` and `sudo systemctl start apiserver` I managed to get the environment up and running again.